# List vs ArrayList vs Dictionary vs Hashtable vs Stack vs Queue?

Tags: c#, collections

We can use any of these (includes List, ArrayList, Dictionary, Hashtable, Stack, Queue) to hold value or hold reference to other objects as a collection.

But, my question is which one is used when?

Comment: You can learn all of .Net and C# by asking a series of questions here, but much easier all round would be to buy a good book!

Comment: @Baboon: No one gets banned for asking questions like this on SO.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This one is already quite bordeline: there is an obvious lack of preliminary research, and the question is too broad. Furthermore, I meant "you can't learn all of .Net and C# by asking a series of questions on SO" because you'll end up asking lots of duplicate, uninteresting, lack-of-research questions

Comment: Microsoft provides a brief comparison [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/#choose-a-collection).

Answer (score 110, accepted):

### Lists

Lists allow duplicate items, can be accessed by index, and support linear traversal.

- **ArrayList** - An array-based list that doesn't support generic types.  It does not enforce type safety and should generally be avoided.
- **List** - An array list that supports generic types and enforces type-safety.  Since it is non-contiguous, it can grow in size without re-allocating memory for the entire list.  This is the more commonly used list collection.

### Hashes

Hashes are look-ups in which you give each item in a list a "key" which will be used to retrieve it later.  Think of a hash like a table index where you can ask questions like "I'm going to find *this* object by *this* string value.  Duplicate keys are not allowed.

- **HashTable** - A basic key-value-pair map that functions like an indexed list.
- **Dictionary** - A hashtable that supports generic types and enforces type-safety.

### Queues

Queues control how items in a list are accessed.  You typically push/pop records from a queue in a particular direction (from either the front or back).  Not used for random access in the middle.

- **Stack** - A LIFO (last in, first out) list where you push/pop records on top of each other.
- **Queue** - A FIFO (first in, first out) list where you push records on top and pop them off the bottom.

Answer (score 15):

- [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) can hold duplicate objects
- [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) is just for compatibility with older versions of the framework where IList didn't exist
- [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is used to store pairs of key/value. You cannot have duplicate keys.
- [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) is basically a List with no possibility of duplicates (and better performance in some scenarios)
- [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) stores objects in order they were added (through `Push()`), and when you retrieve an object (through `Pop()`) it is removed from the stack in a LIFO manner.
- [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) quite similar to a Stack except it is FIFO.

Comment: What is the difference between a) cannot have duplicate keys and b) no possibility of duplicates

Comment: There is no diference in this case. Both could not store duplicate keys. And besides the performance issue, the Hashtable has not generic implementation.

Comment: You haven't differentiated well between Hashtable and Dictionary

Comment: @Chandraprakash To help you and other people looking for an answer: **Hashtable is a loosely typed (non-generic) collection, Dictionary is a generic collection. This means that Hashtable can use both keys and values of any type, Dictionary [asks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0#constructors) during construction what type of keys and values you are going to use.**

Answer (score 4):

Here are some uses for them.

**List:** If you just want a list and don't care about any duplicates, i.e list of people, shopping list, list of things to do in life.

**Queues:** If you want to simulate a queue for example, in a hospital you have a queue and also priority queue (in emergency departments). The triage would determine who is in critical condition and needs to be treated.

Another example is a shopping queue, first person in line is 'usually' the first one to checkout.

**Stacks:** Used in your internal memory to push and pop values as you pass them to functions/methods.

Another interesting use is, in video game inventory method, where you can pick up an item (push) onto the stack, and drop an item (pop) off the stack.

**Hash/Dictionary:** These are usually seen used in database, for look up and index.

Depending on what you want to simulate, I do agree with the others, it's handy to read up on data-structures. A book helps but the internet also has a wealth of information.

Comment: Thanks for the real time examples!!