# how to get corresponding "Name"

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a C# `dictionary` in which I have a corresponding `NAME` against the `ID`.

```
Dictionary<string, List<object>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>
{
    { "ID", new List<object> { "Id1", "Id2" } },
    { "NAME", new List<object> { "True", "False" } }
};

foreach (var id in dict["ID"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(id);
    //how to get corresponding "Name". For "Id1" = "True" and for "Id2" = "False"
}
```

In above code I loop through `ID`, but how to get corresponding `NAME`?

Comment: This is not a very good data structure for this task. It should be a single array instead.

Comment: Ok, could you please explain with some code?

Comment: `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` would be better. The answer indicating to create a separate class would be even better still

Comment: or even `Dictionary<string,bool>`

Comment: @TheGeneral, how to use Dictionary<string,bool>?

Comment: @user584018 GiladGreen Seems to be on the money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *do* have control over dictionary data it's best to either use Gilad's answer and store everything in `List<MyClass>` or to use `Dictionary<string, bool>` :

```
Dictionary<string, bool> dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
{
    { "Id1", true }, { "Id2", false },
};
```

But if you *do not* have control over format of this data and get it as a dictionary from somewhere (for example web service) you could utilize `.Zip` method to convert this dictionary into one list of either anonymous objects/custom class or Tuples, where `Item1` is `Id` and `Item2` is value:

```
// anonymous object
var data = dict["ID"].Zip(dict["NAME"], (x, y) => new
{
   ID = x, 
   NAME = y
}).ToList();

// tuple
// List<Tuple<object, object>> data = dict["ID"].Zip(dict["NAME"], Tuple.Create).ToList();

foreach (var obj in data)
{
   Console.WriteLine(obj.ID + "  " obj.NAME);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Fabjan, I don't have control over dictionary and your solution will be a workaround for me.

Comment: In Tuple, can I put something like `data["Id1"]`?

Comment: @user584018 Tuple is basically a lightweight `struct` that only contains `Item1` and `Item2` as well as some handy methods like `.Create`. If it's does suit your needs you could use custom class/struct or an anonymous object.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! @Fabjan

Answer (score 7):

I think a better design would be to create a class with the two properties and then iterate. If you find yourself having to sync different data structures for simple data representations then I'd suggest rethinking the design.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then hold a `List<MyClass>` which when you iterate:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    // Now access item.Id, item.Name
}
```

---

The use of dictionaries is good when you have some sort of natural key for your data and you want to access access an item by that key. As the items are accessed via a hash function accessing by key is done in `O(1)` whereas searching in a list is `O(n)`. However in your case you are iterating all items in any case so no need for dictionary and arranging the data in a class is a better design.

A bit about the differences and some references:

- [what is the difference between list<> and dictionary<> in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7914830/6400526)
- [List vs ArrayList vs Dictionary vs Hashtable vs Stack vs Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11902107/6400526)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are probably what you should do to better structure your code. *However*, if you *need* to stick to your original use case, you could do something like this:

```
//Depending on what you're dealing with: Dictionary<string, List<string>>
Dictionary<string, List<object>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>{
    {"ID", new List<object>{"Id1", "Id2"}}, 
    {"NAME", new List<object>{"True", "False"}}
};

foreach(var v in dict.Keys){            
    Console.WriteLine($"{v} = {string.Join(",", dict[v])}");
}

//Output:
//ID = Id1,Id2
//NAME = True,False
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have the just the mapping of ID and Name you can have very simple variable

```
  Dictionary<string,string> lookup = new Dictionary<string,string>();
  lookup.Add("ID1","True")
```

and if Name is Boolean type then replace string to bool in the

```
  Dictionary<string,bool> lookup = new Dictionary<string,bool>();
```